# Can a group action be defined by its orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am trying to solve the following qual study problem:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes, and let $G$ be any group of order $pq$. Show that for every integer $n \geq pq$, there exists a set $\Omega$ of cardinality $n$ and a group action of $G$ on $\Omega$ without fixed points (meaning, for each $\alpha \in \Omega$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $g\alpha \neq \alpha$.

I was able to conclude that for such an action, all the orbits must have size $p$, $q$, or $pq$, and for any $\Omega$ of size $n \geq pq$, it is possible to partition $\Omega$ into disjoint sets of size either $p$ or $q$. But is it enough or even possible to define an action by simply specifying each orbit to be a part in this partition? I'm skeptical, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108829/g-set-without-fixed-point-question) seems to imply that it's sufficient.

If not, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: The point is that any number $n \geq pq$ can be written as an integral linear combination $n=ap+bq$. Now use some Sylow theorems

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes, I was able to prove that you can write $n = ap + bq$. My question was asking, what next? How do you specify an action from that? (I like the answer given below, but if you have a different method that uses the Sylow theorems, I'd love to hear it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a partition $\Omega = \coprod_{i=1}^n \Omega_i$ into pairwise disjoint subsets $\Omega_i \subseteq \Omega$ of size $|\Omega_i| \in \{p,q\}$, it sufficies to construct an action of $G$ on each $\Omega_i$ without fixed points.
By combining these actions, we then get an action of $G$ on the whole of $\Omega$ without fixed points.

Instead of using the $\Omega_i$, it sufficies to show that there exists actions of $G$ on some sets of cardinalty $p$ and $q$ without fixed points.

- It follows from $|G| = pq$ that $G$ contains a subgroup $H \subseteq G$ of order $|H| = p$ (one can use Sylow’s theorems or Cauchy’s theorem to see this).
  Then the action of $G$ on the set of left cosets $G/H$ given by
  $$
      g \cdot g'H
    = (gg')H
  $$ is transitive, and because $|G/H| = |G|/|H| = q \neq 1$ it follows that this action has no fixed points.
- By swapping the roles of $p$ and $q$ we can also construct an action of $G$ on a set with $p$ elements without fixed points.